# Port 443 Exact use and description

Tags: port

I had studied on many sites but got confused about port 443

Anyone please provide me complete information on Port no 443.
Thanks for your response.
Is it only for http or also used for ssl or any other

Comment: It is the standard port for https

Comment: maybe give us more background information of what you want to do?

Comment: Port 443 is the standard port for https communication and it's not for HTTP. It's for secure communication over HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

A port can be used for basically anything that is to be exposed on the network, 443 is no different from any other port really. But, I'm guessing you don't want info about how ports work, but rather what port 443 is used for by most often.

Port `443` is the default port for *secure HTTP* aka *https*, that is, http with **T**ransport **L**ayer **S**ecurity (earlier called **S**ecure **S**ockets **L**ayer). Just as with `http`, it's a port that web servers uses but unlike standard http enforces the usage of secure certificates, most often created by a Certificate Authority that is known by the web browsers as a secure authority.

So when connecting to a page via `https` instead of `http`, using a certificate which the browser (or computer) have either added as a safe certificate or have not. If not, it will tell you so and show an exception or warning (at least most browsers will do that).
TLS requires the certificates, and the reason is that the server encrypts the data that it sends to the client, and then the client decrypt it making the whole stream of data less easy to catch for someone whom should not have the data, i.e., a hacker or similar.

If you are running a webpage, you should make sure that you have valid certificates. Both Chrome and Firefox marks pages without TLS as unsafe and if you have any type of data transfer from page to server (say a form with data for the user to add for example) TLS is pretty much a must to make the data transfer safe.

TLS certificates used to be quite costly, but now a days there are services such as [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) and [Cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com/) which provides safe and free certificates, either as one you install on the server, or a shared certificate as in the "free" version from Cloudflare.

Personally I find it worth to create a self signed certificate (a certificate from my own Certificate Authority, not a big one which is validated by the browsers) for local development too and add it to the certificate storage so that even my `localhost` uses TLS, but that might be overkill in some cases.

---

TLDR;
The port `443` is often used for HTTPS (http with TLS), it's good. Use it.

Comment: No problems, feel free to mark the answer as correct (if you feel that it was) so that it shows up as a solved question in search engines :)